# Write cyrillic letters into mysql with python

Tags: python, mysql, encoding

I have script that parse data from txt file(I think its utf8) and then it should write it to mysql. 
When I do something like that:

```
cur.execute("insert into keywords (keyword) values ('%s')" % (u'RUSSIAN TEXT HERE'))
```

**it do the job well**(I have russian string in my mysqldb), but when I

```
f = open('/Users/aaaa/Desktop/keywords.txt', 'rw+')
for x in range (14028):
    a = f.readline(x)
    cur.execute("insert into keywords (keyword) values ('%s')" % (a))
    #or that
    cur.execute("insert into keywords (keyword) values ('%s')" % (unicode(a)))
```

then I get this

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have this in my mysql

```
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  utf8
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/local/mysql-5.6.20-osx10.8-x86_64/share/charsets/
```

Occasionally, I wrote simbols into database, but russian symbols was  like squares and stuff.
What should I do?

Also, I get this after repr(a)

```
''
'0'
'5 '
'ru '
'\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0'
'\xd1\x85\xd0\xb0\xd1'
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: NEVER use the `%` operator to parametrize SQL queries. While using `%s` is correct, you have to pass the actual data tuple as another argument to `cur.execute()` - otherwise you perform string interpolation which leaves you open to sql injection.

Comment: ok thanks. But what should I do, to write data into mysql?

Comment: `print repr(a)` and post what it is when you crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to open file this way:

`f = open('/Users/aaaa/Desktop/keywords.txt', 'rw+', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: f = codecs.open('/Users/alexeypolusov/Desktop/keywords.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='rw+') here it is! THANKS DUDE